# Derivative of $p(x)=f(g(h(k(x))))$

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have some arbitrary function:

$p(x)=f(g(h(k(x))))$

and I want to take the derivative of this with respect to x. I know how to apply the chain rule to a simpler function like

$y(x)=f(g(x))$

$y'(x)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$

but I am not really sure how I would apply the chain rule to p(x).

Would it look something like this:

$p'(x)=f'(g(h(k(x))))\cdot g'(h(k(x)))\cdot h'(k(x))\cdot k'(x)$

or am I making a mistake?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Is it better to use Leibniz' or Newton's notation when computing these kinds of derivatives or is that just personal preference?

Comment: Yes, your idea is correct: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: See for yourself: $$\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dg}\frac{dg}{dh}\frac{dh}{dk}\frac{dk}{dx} $$

Comment: Personally I prefer Leibniz's notation.